# Choosing a distribution in the presence of multiplicative observation errors

Tags: distributions, measurement-error, lognormal-distribution

Suppose I have a large sample from some distribution the form of which I do not know with certainty, though it would appear to be continuous and reasonably well-behaved (e.g. unimodal, differentiable) . Suppose I have compared the fit of a number of likely candidates and find some particular distribution – call it $G(x)$ –fits both best and well. So I think my data has a $G$ distribution.

Then I learn that the data is probably observed with error, and that the errors on $\ln(G(x))$ are probably distributed normally, i.e. the percentage error on each observation is approximately iid normal, or the error is lognormal. So now I think the data underlying data-generating process has a different distribution – call it $H$ –and I would like to figure out what it is.

If my original conclusion that the data as observed, including the error, has a $G$ distribution is correct, can I conclude anything about the form of the true, error-free distribution? If $G$ is a standard, closed form distribution, is there any appreciable possibility that $H$ will also have a closed form? Is there a way of recovering $H$ from the distribution of $G$ and the form of the error process, either just knowing that proportional errors are normal or if I also have some way of estimating the parameters of the error distribution?

Comment: a) Beware notation! If $X\sim G$ the distribution of $\log(X)$ is **not** $\log G$! .  b) If you take the log of your random variable, the errors will be additive. Work on that log scale with the nice additive normal errors. You then have a problem akin to deconvolution (if you know the variance of the additive noise, it's even more like one). The resulting distribution of the log-observations would be the convolution of the original (without-error) distribution of the logs and the normal log-errors. If you want to use the sample to estimate all the unknown parameters of both, it will be hard.