# If the relative error is normally distributed, the error is log-normally distributed?

Tags: error, lognormal-distribution

I've read in various places that having a log-normal distribution on the error in a random process makes sense when the relative error (or percentage error) is normally distributed. I can't seem to find a way to formalize this, however. Any ideas?

Comment: Where did you read this ?

Comment: The following [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60695/choosing-a-distribution-in-the-presence-of-multiplicative-observation-errors) and [this blog post](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2016/09/relative-error-distributions-without-the-heavy-tail-theatrics/) (although the latter doesn't say that the relative error should be normally distributed; it's a bit vague).

Comment: One way--perhaps the only way--this assertion can be true is when the true underlying value does not vary.  This indicates we need more information: what is the context?  Exactly how is "relative error" in your process defined?

Comment: Yes, in my case the true underlying value does not vary. I have a set of measured quantities that I know have some measurement error, and that the error on each one is relative to its magnitude (and approximately normally distributed).